Looking for Experts to Assist with AppExchange Security Review
We’re currently facing challenges with the AppExchange security review process for our managed package. The application integrates Salesforce with an external Node.js-based web application.
While we’ve addressed most issues within the Salesforce managed package, previous security reviews have flagged concerns with the external web application. We’re looking for guidance or expert assistance from someone familiar with navigating Salesforce security reviews, particularly in scenarios involving external web applications.
If you know of any professionals who can help, please share their contact information or point us in the right direction.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Although your exact question is unclear, I guess you need clarity w.r.t. external endpoint scanning. You can refer this answer if it helps. Else please edit the question to ask a specific doubt.
